# How can I center this get echo

Tags: php, css, wordpress, echo, centering

Im sure this is super simple, all I am trying to do is center the image on the page using this.

```
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap a div round it in the function. But ideally code and html should be separated.

Comment: You should mention that get_the_post_thumbnail() is a WordPress library function and tag appropriately. Syntax is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'center-img' ) );
```

And in your style.css create a class center-img:

```
.center-img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to do this. Cannot provide a working example without more context, but it may look something like this..

#### HTML

```
<div class="thePostThumbnail">
  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ); ?>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.thePostThumbnail {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it inside a div and use css.

```
<div align="center">
  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be better done in the function. Ideally code and html should be separated.

Comment: I agree. I was just answering the simple question with the little context provided. I don't know about function, style sheet, html, etc. Fair down vote though.